# transpose row into a single column with pivot or decode in dual table - Oracle

Tags: oracle

If i give this query,

Select 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 from dual;

It will look like this

```
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  - column names
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  - Associated values
```

But i want to show like this

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

I don't know how to do this with dual table

Answer (score 1):

"Unpivot version":

```
select val from (select 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 from dual)
unpivot (val for tmp in ("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"))
```

Simpler alternative giving the same results:

```
select * from table(sys.odcinumberlist(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `union all`:

```
select 1 as name from dual union all
select 2 as name from dual union all
select 3 as name from dual union all
select 4 as name from dual union all
select 5 as name from dual union all
select 6 as name from dual union all
select 7 as name from dual union all
select 8 as name from dual union all
select 9 as name from dual;
```

Comment: Thats ok,but i want to know if i can do that with pivot or decode function?

Comment: Or else can anyone know how to do this with unpivot function?